# Move Constructor and Move assign. operator in base class

Tags: c++

```
struct foo_base
{
    explicit foo_base(int i) : i(i) {}
    foo_base() = delete;
    virtual ~foo_base() = default;
    int i;
}
```

My class is not managing resources, but I've declared virtual destructor because for it's polymorphic usage. As far as I understand this way I've deleted move constructor and move assig.operator. It's ok to keep it like this or it will be safer or correct to make move constructor and move assig.operator as default too?

Comment: Copy and move semantics with polymorphism is always a touchy subject because it may expose you to object slicing. It depends on whether or not you expect the derived types to support them.

Comment: Since it doesn't hold any resource, chance are that it's cheap to copy.

Comment: [Tangential] `foo_base() = delete;` is not needed since you have `explicit foo_base(int i) : i(i) {}` which implicitly deletes the default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand this way I've deleted move constructor and move assig.operator.

Correct.

Although, do note that the copy constructor and assignment operator are implicitly generated, and therefore the class is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable.

> It's ok to keep it like this or it will be safer or correct to make move constructor and move assig.operator as default too?

It makes little difference in terms of safety. It would be useful in the case the base has members that have efficiently movable members (such as a vector) or non-copyable members. But `foo_base` doesn't have those.

It may be better to keep the class simpler by not defaulting explicitly. For same reasoning, it may be better to not explicitly delete the default constructor is unnecessary, which would be implicitly deleted anyway.

Whether you should choose explicitness or reduction of noise is heavily based on opinion.